# MPI_Get only reads the first element of an array from the shared memory area

Tags: c++, mpi, shared-memory

I am trying to access shared memory area containing one-dimensional array using MPI_Get function. Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <mpi.h>

void initVector(int* vec, int vecSize)
{
    srand(static_cast<unsigned>(time(NULL)));

    for (int i = 0; i < vecSize; i++)
        vec[i] = std::rand() % 10 + 1;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    int commSize{ 0 };
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &commSize);

    int myRank{ 0 };
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myRank);

    MPI_Comm MPI_COMM_SHARED{ 0 };
    MPI_Comm_split_type(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, myRank, MPI_INFO_NULL, &MPI_COMM_SHARED);

    int nodeSize{ 0 };
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_SHARED, &nodeSize);

    int nodeRank{ 0 };
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_SHARED, &nodeRank);

    int* masterInVector{ nullptr };
    MPI_Win vectorWinHandle{ 0 };
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(commSize * sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_SHARED, &masterInVector, &vectorWinHandle);

    int* slaveInVector{ masterInVector };
    MPI_Aint winSizeVector{ 0 };
    int winDispVector{ 0 };

    if (nodeRank != 0)
    {
        MPI_Win_shared_query(vectorWinHandle, 0, &winSizeVector, &winDispVector, &slaveInVector);
    }

    if (nodeRank == 0)
    {
        MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, 0, MPI_MODE_NOCHECK, vectorWinHandle);
        initVector(slaveInVector, commSize);
        MPI_Win_unlock(0, vectorWinHandle);
    }

    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    int vectorCell{ -1 };
    for (int i = 0; i < commSize; i++)
    {
        MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, 0, MPI_MODE_NOCHECK, vectorWinHandle);
        MPI_Get(&vectorCell, 1, MPI_INT, 0, winSizeVector + (i * sizeof(int)), 1, MPI_INT, vectorWinHandle);
        MPI_Win_unlock(0, vectorWinHandle);
        std::cout << "[" << myRank << "]" << vectorCell << std::endl;
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

and the output message for 2 processors:

```
[0]2
[0]0
[1]-1
[1]-1
```

The expected output for 2 processors (keep in mind that the output values are randomly generated in the `initVector` fuction):

```
[0]2
[0]2
[1]7
[1]7
```

First processor (`myRank=0`) during the first iteration of a for loop reads the appropriate value from the shared memory, during the second iteration reads 0 value from the second element in the array.
Second processor (`myRank=1`) does not read anything regardless of iteration (because the `vectorCell=-1`).
Any idea what is the problem?

Comment: How big should be your shared memory ? `commSize*sizeof(int)` ? `commSize*commSize*sizeof(int)` ? why do you add `winSizeVector` to `target_disp` ?

Comment: Shared memory should be `commSize * sizeof(int)` - an array with `commSize` number of elements. `winSizeVector` is the mistake. I have corrected it to `commSize * sizeof(int)` and now it still shows the incorrect result i.e: [0]10 \n [0]0 \n [1]10 \n [1]10 \n.

Comment: Then you should `MPI_Win_allocate_shared()` 0 elements on rank != 0

Comment: For the sake of debugging, you should also initialize the shared memory with deterministic values.

Comment: I have changed `MPI_Win_allocate_shared`'s parameter `disp_unit` to 1 so the `MPI_Get(..., i * sizeof(int), ...)` actually works. I also corrected the shared memory allocation (as you said) so, only rank 0 allocates memory now. Memory allocation using `MPI_Win_allocate_shared()` automatically assigns deterministic values to that memory area (i.e. 0 value) so, I don't have to do anything special regarding the initialization. Now, I am struggling with 2D array initialization in the shared memory area - but it is another topic.

Comment: good catch, I missed that too. note it would be more elegant to keep `disp_unit=sizeof(int)` but use `target_disp=i` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is connected with `disp_unit` parameter of `MPI_Win_allocate_shared(...)` function. According to [specification](https://www.open-mpi.org/doc/v2.0/man3/MPI_Win_allocate_shared.3.php):

> Common choices for disp_unit are 1 (no scaling), and (in C syntax) sizeof(type), for a window that consists of an array of elements of type type. [...]

There was a mismatch between the `disp_unit` and `target_disp` parameters of `MPI_Win_allocate_shared(...)` and `MPI_Get(...)` functions. So the code would look like:

```
// ...
MPI_Win_allocate_shared(commSize * sizeof(int), sizeof(int), MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_SHARED, &masterInVector, &vectorWinHandle);
// ...
int vectorCell{ -1 };
for (int i = 0; i < commSize; i++)
{
    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, 0, MPI_MODE_NOCHECK, vectorWinHandle);
    MPI_Get(&vectorCell, 1, MPI_INT, 0, i, 1, MPI_INT, vectorWinHandle);
    MPI_Win_unlock(0, vectorWinHandle);
    std::cout << "[" << myRank << "]" << vectorCell << std::endl;
}
// ...
```

If we assume that `disp_unit = 1` then the equivalent code would be:

```
// ...
MPI_Win_allocate_shared(commSize * sizeof(int), 1, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_SHARED, &masterInVector, &vectorWinHandle);
// ...
int vectorCell{ -1 };
for (int i = 0; i < commSize; i++)
{
    MPI_Win_lock(MPI_LOCK_EXCLUSIVE, 0, MPI_MODE_NOCHECK, vectorWinHandle);
    MPI_Get(&vectorCell, 1, MPI_INT, 0, i * sizeof(int), 1, MPI_INT, vectorWinHandle);
    MPI_Win_unlock(0, vectorWinHandle);
    std::cout << "[" << myRank << "]" << vectorCell << std::endl;
}
// ...
```